# how to search dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search dates in mysql however, if the column type is date it doesn't work. I need to change to text type is the any way to do it date type

here is my query

```
SELECT Count(CaseStatus) as CompletedCase From checkfinale where CaseStatus='2' AND CompanyID='51' AND `CompletedDate` BETWEEN '2012-05-29' AND '2012-06-05'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also specify dates as simply YYYYMMDD

```
BETWEEN 20120529 AND 20120605
```

Comment: I have tried to use both CAST and the way you showed both are not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting a mysql error? Also, what's the output of `DESC checkfinale;` ?

Comment: I check it is actually varchar data type. I think because it is view.

Comment: Ok, you are actually storing strings rather than dates. You may want to convert them to the proper type. The only way that query is working at the moment is that the date format you've chosen works ok for comparing alphabetically. In other words "2012-05-29" > "2012-04-02" is true.

Answer (score 1):

As described at the following link, try CASTing your constant strings for comparison: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

```
AND `CompletedDate` BETWEEN CAST('2012-05-29' AS DATE) AND CAST('2012-06-05' AS DATE)
```

Comment: I tried to use it no result. it seems that it works only in text type column. I cannot understand why

Comment: Are you sure that CompletedDate is of type Date? Whatever type it is is what you need to cast as. Further, if you have been converting these columns between types, it's worth checking if it still contains the data you expect it to. BETWEEN has always worked great for me with DATE columns.